# Converting a date time string into another format

Tags: python

I have two date time string in this format

```
2019-07-09T19:42:19,002Z
2019-07-09T12:42:19,000-0700
```

and I need to convert these two date time strings into this format

```
2019-07-09T19:42:19.002+00:00
2019-07-09T12:42:19.000-07:00
```

I've tried

```
dt = parser.parse(dateTime)
ldt = parser.parse(localDateTime)
```

but that gives me this

```
dt = 2019-07-09 19:42:19.002000+00:00
ldt = 2019-07-09 12:42:19-07:00
```

Which doesn't include the "T" in both. And the milliseconds needs to be truncated to three digits in dt.

For reference the first 2 date time values adhere to ISO 8601 and I need it to adhere to RFC 3339.

```
from dateutil import parser

dateTime = '2019-07-09T19:42:19,002Z'
localDateTime = '2019-07-09T12:42:19,000-0700'

dt = parser.parse(dateTime)
ldt = parser.parse(localDateTime)
```

Comment: you can format output `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%S.%f%z')` but it still gives 6 digits for milliseconds

Comment: with string formating I can get 3 digits for milliseconds `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%S.{:03}%z'.format(dt.microsecond//1000)`

Answer (score 1):

how about: 
datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%fZ")

Comment: I just ran dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m%dT%H:%M:%S,%fZ")
print(dt) and it returned 2019-07-09 19:42:19.002000. That's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: dt = "2019-07-09T19:42:19,002Z"

t = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%fZ")
print(t)
# 2019-07-09 19:42:19.002000
print(t.isoformat('T'))
# 2019-07-09T19:42:19.002000